# ng-modal undefined in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<ion-view view-title="Categories">
  <ion-content> 

   <form >
        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input">
  <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
  <input  type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-modal="searchText"/>
</label> 
</div>
</form>


    <ion-list>

<button ng-click="setCode(searchText)">Check!</button>
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="category in categories |filter:filtercat|filter:searchText" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/category/{{category.ID}}">

        <h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{category.slug}}</p>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>

        <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(chat)">
         {{searchText}}
        </ion-option-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I want to use search option in ionic framework. Here ng-modal is undefined and input search is not working. I want to use search through angularjs code.

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its **ng-model**. Not ng-modal. For more information check this. [Official Docs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)